# Can't get .bashrc to load

Tags: bashrc

I can't get .bashrc to load on this machine... it's SUZE linux 10.  I'm a bit frustrated because this seems very basic, create the file and it loads when you open a new shell connection.  With the below setup I'm not seeing my changes take affect... any suggestions?  I've looked over at least 8-10 threads on StackOverflow and ServerFault and haven't found a working solution.

**.bash_profile**

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

**.bashrc**

```
# Define a few Colours
BLACK='\e[0;30m'
BLUE='\e[0;34m'
GREEN='\e[0;32m'
CYAN='\e[0;36m'
RED='\e[0;31m'
PURPLE='\e[0;35m'
BROWN='\e[0;33m'
LIGHTGRAY='\e[0;37m'
DARKGRAY='\e[1;30m'
LIGHTBLUE='\e[1;34m'
LIGHTGREEN='\e[1;32m'
LIGHTCYAN='\e[1;36m'
LIGHTRED='\e[1;31m'
LIGHTPURPLE='\e[1;35m'
YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
WHITE='\e[1;37m'
NC='\e[0m'              # No Color

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does the global profile (usually in /etc/profile) tell it to load any user profiles?

this can be simply done by:

```
if [ -f /home/$USER/.bash_profile ]; then
  source /home/$USER/.bash_profile
fi
```